# Fuzzy module not working for me

Tags: python, ubuntu-14.04, spyder, fuzzywuzzy

I'm having problem with this [fuzzy module](https://github.com/seatgeek/fuzzywuzzy)
 because when I try to run the second part of the code which is:

```
fuzz.partial_ratio("this is a test", "this is a test!")
```

it gives an error like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-44-f5783c7c4393>", line 1, in <module>
    fuzz.partial_ratio("this is a test", "this is a test!")

  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/fuzzywuzzy/utils.py", line 23, in decorator
    return func(*args, **kwargs)

  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/fuzzywuzzy/utils.py", line 32, in decorator
    return func(*args, **kwargs)

  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/fuzzywuzzy/fuzz.py", line 69, in partial_ratio
    blocks = m.get_matching_blocks()

  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/fuzzywuzzy/StringMatcher.py", line 58, in get_matching_blocks
    self._str1, self._str2)

TypeError: inverse expected a list of edit operations
```

and the second one when I try to run the last part:

```
process.extractOne("cowboys", choices)
```

it gives an error like this :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-45-8f425ac79b9d>", line 1, in <module>
    process.extractOne("cowboys", choices)

  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/fuzzywuzzy/process.py", line 161, in extractOne
    best_list = extract(query, choices, processor, scorer, limit=1)

  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/fuzzywuzzy/process.py", line 110, in extract
    score = scorer(query, processed)

  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/fuzzywuzzy/fuzz.py", line 247, in WRatio
    partial = partial_ratio(p1, p2) * partial_scale

  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/fuzzywuzzy/utils.py", line 23, in decorator
    return func(*args, **kwargs)

  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/fuzzywuzzy/utils.py", line 32, in decorator
    return func(*args, **kwargs)

  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/fuzzywuzzy/fuzz.py", line 69, in partial_ratio
    blocks = m.get_matching_blocks()

  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/fuzzywuzzy/StringMatcher.py", line 58, in get_matching_blocks
    self._str1, self._str2)

TypeError: inverse expected a list of edit operations
```

all other code is working well except for these two. How do I fix this? I'm currently using ubuntu 14.04LTS and Spyder to run python.

Edit: I have attempted to reinstall levenshtein, fuzzywuzzy and difflib module. Still the same problem occur. Is it because I'm using ubuntu? because when I try to run using my dual boot windows 10, it works!

Answer (score 0):

try uninstall fuzzywuzyy and

```
 pip install fuzzywuzzy[speedup]
```

This error is due the old version of python-Levenshtein